# Are electrons and holes distinguishable particles?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, identical-particles

In condensed matter physics: If we describe e.g. an exciton as a combination of an electron and a hole, do we need to combine them in a Slater determinant or into a simple product state? What happens with exchange interactions?

Comment: There will be a splitting between singlet and triplet states, and this normally called the exchange. But yes, I see a conceptual difficulty. The energy difference is larger in small systems (molecules, quantum dots).

Answer (score 2):

A hole is an abstraction of a missing electron, that is of a many electron system with spin 1/2. The wave function of the total system is antisymmetric under exchange of participating electrons. This implies that there is effectively exchange interaction between the hole and electron that occupied it.